# Zeus + FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods. undefined method `create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, zeus

I have:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

which properly work with simple `rspec spec/model/user_spec.rb` (allows me to use `create(:user)`, not `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`).
But if I use `zeus rspec spec/model/user_spec.rb` to speed up my specs, it troughs me an error:

```
Failure/Error: @user = create(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `create' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x007fc8618e4960>
```

How I can use this syntax with zeus?

Comment: ``zeus rake spec`` works fine for me, with factory girl.

Comment: It seems to be only if run specific spec. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 28):

Remove either of these lines in spec/spec_helper.rb if they exist:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'rspec/autotest'
```

Comment: Do you know why this breaks FactoryGirl? This seems like a band-aid.

Comment: This also works for getting rspec-fire working with zeus

Answer (score 1):

Did you previously use spork on this project? If so, you have to remove the parts that Spork changed in your `spec_helper`. Like @ilake-chang said, you have to remove the `require 'rspec/autorun'` and you'll also want to remove `Spork.prefork` and `Spork.each_run`.

See [the Zeus wiki on Spork](https://github.com/burke/zeus/wiki/Spork)